# Can and organization use separate Windows Server 2012 AD as bridge server to windows 2008 AD server to be able to federate to an Application?

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, ws-federation, adfs3.0, federation

I hope I am clear on explaining the issue since I am very new to AFDS and federation world.

Here is the requirement.

Customer has windows 2008 and ADFS 2.0 (which doesn't not have any plan what so ever to upgrade their servers to new versions) trying to federate with our Application which only support ADFS 3.0 and above.

Is it possible to use a windows server 2012 with adfs 3.X as a bridge server that can have trust relation with their windows 2008 AD and use 2012 to federate with our application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - simply federate your ADFS 3.0 with their ADFS 2.0.

Just swop metadata and decide who will be the CP and who will be the RP. So on the one side add the ADFS as a claims provider and on the other side add the ADFS as a relying party.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Is this a common solution for this scenario? I have been googling for a while to find an article that can suggest this solution but haven't found anything.

Comment: Why does your application only support ADFS 3.0 and above? What protocol is it using e.g. WIF, WS-Fed?

Comment: Also, the trust relationship is between ADFS not between AD. But yes, to answer your question. User goes to your app, redirected to ADFS 3.0, chooses ADFS 2.0 from Home Realm Discovery screen, authenticates on 2008.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad! our application is using WS-fed protocol.

Comment: i found this, seems suggest what you are suggestion, or am I wrong?
https://www.yobyot.com/aws/connect-two-ad-fs-federation-servers/2015/02/11/

Comment: Yes - the part about metadata and claims configuration is the way to go.